# Batch For Loop Escape Asterisk

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, escaping

I am attempting to create a batch for loop (Windows XP and newer command prompts) that iterates through a string containing one or more asterisks.  How can I do this?  Here is an example:

```
@FOR %%A IN (A* B) DO @ECHO %%A
```

The expected output (what I am trying to get) is the following:

```
A*  
B
```

However, what I am actually getting with the command above is B and only B.  For some reason, everything with an asterisk is being ignored by the loop.  I have attempted escaping the asterisk with 1-4 carets (^), backslashes (\), percent signs (%), and other asterisks (*), all to no avail.  Thanks in advance for illuminating me.

IN CASE YOU WANT MORE INFORMATION:

The purpose of this is to parse a path out of a list of space-separated partial paths.  For example, I want to copy C:\Bar\A.txt, C:\Bar\B.txt, and C:\Bar\C*.txt to C:\Foo\ using the following approach:

```
@SET FILE_LIST=A B C*  
@FOR %%A IN (%FILE_LIST%) DO @COPY C:\Bar\%%A.txt C:\Foo\
```

If there is another alternative way to do this (preferably without typing each and every copy command since there are ~200 files, which is the same reason I don't want to store the full path for every file), I would appreciate the help.  Thanks again,

-Jeff

Comment: Do you need to copy ALL files in the `Bar` folder? Or do you have only certain files you wish to copy? If there are only certain files, do they share a common name? Are you moving all `.txt` files? You can explain to us what your real-life application is. We promise we won't track you down to steal your data =D. Except maybe Jeb =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
@echo off
set "it=a*b .txt-b*.txt-c*.txt-d.txt"
set /a i=0,fn=3
:startLoop
set /a i=i+1
for /f "tokens=%i%delims=-" %%m in ("%it%") do echo %%m
if %i% lss %fn% goto:startLoop
```

Answer (score 2):

the asterisks works the way its intended, in your case,

```
@FOR %%A IN (A* B) DO @ECHO %%A
```

expands A* to all the files that begin with A.

A possible way to do what you want, is just to use this expansion

```
@ECHO off
PUSHD C:\bar
SET FILE_LIST=A.txt B.txt C*.txt
FOR %%A IN (%FILE_LIST%) DO (
  IF EXIST %%A COPY %%A C:\Foo\
)
POPD
```